# replacing characters dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a series of strings I need to alter based on some criteria, and I'm trying to build a list of words to replace in the string like so:

```
test = "CAPTAIN AMERICA TO SUPERMAN"

delimeters = ['AND', 'TO', 'THEN']
delimited_speaker_string = ""
for delimeter in delimeters:
    delimeter_txt = ' {} '.format(delimeter)
    delimited_speaker_string = test.replace(delimeter_txt, ' @ ')

print(delimited_speaker_string)
```

The goal is to have `CAPTAIN AMERICA @ SUPERMAN` but I just get the original string, why?

Comment: Did you, by chance, mean to have your print statement inside the loop? Or perhaps, you meant to accumulate the changes in each iteration in a variable like `test` or `delimited_speaker_string`?

Comment: Initialize `delimited_speaker_string`  as `delimited_speaker_string = test` and make sure to use the intermediary value while updating `delimited_speaker_string = delimited_speaker_string.replace(delimeter_txt, ' @ ')`

Comment: @flakes that was it! I can't believe I didn't see it, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace whole words then you need to break down the input string into tokens (words) as follows:

```
test: str = "CAPTAIN AMERICA TO SUPERMAN"
delimiters: list[str] = ['AND', 'TO', 'THEN']

tokens: list[str] = test.split()

for delimiter in delimiters:
    try:
        tokens[tokens.index(delimiter)] = "@"
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(" ".join(tokens))
```

**Output:**

```
CAPTAIN AMERICA @ SUPERMAN
```

Using str.replace() as suggested elsewhere can produce ambiguous results.

Of course, you could use the *re* module like this:

```
from re import compile

test: str = "CAPTAIN AMERICA TO SUPERMAN"
delimiters: list[str] = ['AND', 'TO', 'THEN']

p = compile("|".join((rf"\b{_d}\b" for _d in delimiters)))

print(p.sub("@", test))
```